# Leaflet: strech map to fit the browser width

Tags: leaflet

Is there a way to stretch the tiles of a map to fit the given width? Now, the width of the map is less than its height, and it fits half of my monitor.

Comment: Could you include your code in the question or create a JSBin/JSFiddle with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ziluval/1/edit?css,output). The width of the map stretches across the available space.

This is the CSS I use in it:

```
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```